# numpy .npz load returns BadZipfile: File is not a zip file after a certain size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compression

I am saving a large numpy array of shape (40,000, 450, 600, 3).

The array is built by a `for` loop that converts jpg images to (450, 600, 3) ndarrays and appending the array to the 4 dimensional array and saving it using the `numpy.savez_compressed` function.

for the first few hundred iterations the `numpy.load('file.npz')` function works fine and I am able to recover my saved npz file. But at some point I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 14, in <module>
numpycom = np.load('img_one.npz')
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.6/site-  
packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 373, in load
return NpzFile(fid, own_fid=own_fid)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.6/site- 
packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 185, in __init__
_zip = zipfile_factory(fid)
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python2.6/site-
packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 124, in zipfile_factory
return zipfile.ZipFile(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/zipfile.py", line 696, in __init__
self._GetContents()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/zipfile.py", line 716, in _GetContents
self._RealGetContents()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/zipfile.py", line 728, in _RealGetContents
raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
Exception AttributeError: "'NpzFile' object has no attribute 'zip'" in 
<bound method NpzFile.__del__ of <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 
0x2fe4110>> ignored
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Does the problem only arise when your zip file exceeds either 2GB or 4GB? Historically, there have been issues with the handling of zip files that big.

Comment: what is the best way to have the script read out disk and memory as it is saving compressing? if i used the sys.getsizeof() function in python, a numpy array that I instantiate is 200GB, it is a 400000x450x600x3 array.